# How to send multipart/related request in Play

Tags: scala, http, tesseract, playframework-2.3, multipart

I'm integrating my scala 2.11.6, playframework 2.3.8 with open-ocr (tesseract) and it requires to send multipart/related data.

I'm trying to do it, manually generating multipart request

```
        val postBody = s"""--separator--
                |Content-Type: application/json;
                |
                | { "engine": "tesseract" }
                |
                |--separator--
                | Content-Type: image/png;
                |
                | ${Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image)}
                |--separator--
            """.stripMargin
        val parseResult = WS.
            url("http://127.0.0.1:9292/ocr-file-upload").
            withMethod("POST").
            withHeaders(
                "Content-Type" -> "multipart/related",
                "boundary" -> "separator").
            withBody(postBody).
            execute()
```

But it does not work. Open-ocr can't read headers of requests.

How can I do this?

Comment: What does not work? Could you be more precise?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Open-ocr can't read the headers of requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, that I used is to generate body manually, using ning Multipart response generator.

With old version **1.8.0**:

```
import com.ning.http.client.FluentCaseInsensitiveStringsMap
import com.ning.http.client.multipart._

...

    // Step 1. Generating tesseract json configuration
    val json = new StringPart("config", """{ "engine": "tesseract" }""", "utf-8")
    json.setContentType("application/json")
    // Step 2. Generating file part
    val filePart = new FilePart("file", new ByteArrayPartSource("image.png", image), "image/png", null)
    // Step 3. Build up the Multiparts
    val reqE = new MultipartRequestEntity(
        Array(filePart, json),
        new FluentCaseInsensitiveStringsMap().add("Content-Type", "multipart/related")
    )
    // Step 3.1. Streaming result to byte array
    val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    reqE.writeRequest(bos)
    // Step 4. Performing WS request upload request
    val parseResult = WS
        .url("http://127.0.0.1:9292/ocr-file-upload")
        .withHeaders("Content-Type" -> reqE.getContentType()).
        post(bos.toByteArray());
    // Step 5. Mapping result to parseResult
    parseResult.map(_.body)
```

With latest version **1.9.31**:

```
import com.ning.http.client.FluentCaseInsensitiveStringsMap
import com.ning.http.client.multipart._

...

    // Step 1. Generating tesseract json configuration
    val json = new StringPart("config", """{ "engine": "tesseract" }""", "application/json", Charset.forName("utf-8"))
    // Step 2. Generating file part
    val filePart = new ByteArrayPart("image.png", scaledImage, "image/png")
    // Step 3. Build up the Multiparts
    val reqE = MultipartUtils.newMultipartBody(
        util.Arrays.asList(filePart, json),
        new FluentCaseInsensitiveStringsMap().add("Content-Type", "multipart/related")
    )
    // Step 3.1. Streaming result to byte array
    val bos = ByteBuffer.allocate(scaledImage.length + 1024)
    reqE.read(bos)
    // Step 4. Performing WS request upload request
    val parseResult = WS
        .url("http://127.0.0.1:9292/ocr-file-upload")
        .withHeaders("Content-Type" -> reqE.getContentType())
        .post(bos.array());
    // Step 5. Mapping result to parseResult
    parseResult.map(_.body)
```

Comment: Thanks you. Do you know how to parse the request ?